# Notification Icon on UITabBar

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I can't find any reference to add a 'notification' to an icon, preferably into a UITabBar, like the image attached, number 8.

I suppose I don't have to create manually ALL the numbers inside a circle, or create it every time I need and update the image manually with some of my icons ?

thanks,

r.

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check out the [`badgeValue` property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006928-CH3-SW16) of `UITabBarItem`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't find the UITabBarItem Class Reference :-(

r.

Answer (score 3):

```
 UITabBarItem *item = [self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];  
 item.badgeValue = @"8";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
self.newsTabBarItem = (UITabBarItem *)[stTabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
self.friendsTabBarItem = (UITabBarItem *)[stTabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
```